# Dispatch click event and keep keystroke modifiers

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, modifier-key

I would like to listen to a click event on a particular element and then dispatch it to a link element while keeping in mind if the meta key was hold or not.

For instance:
Let's say I have a table of elements. When the user clicks on a row I would like to follow a link, but I would like the link to be opened in a new tab if the user had his <kbd>⌘</kbd> /<kbd>ctrl</kbd> key pressed.

It seems simple but I found out this was tricky... (As I didn't succeed to do it!)

Answer (score 1):

The DOM Event API already provides all you need, assuming you need only to *remember* the modifier keys from a legitimate user action.

When using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) to catch an event, simply take the parameter, which is a `DOMEvent` instance, that is passed to your handler function, and resend it to your target element with [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dispatchEvent)  :)

Indeed, a `DOMEvent` instance encapsulates its source environment. More specifically here, a [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MouseEvent) knows which keys were pressed when it was fired.

---

Demo: try clicking the link in [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JAmtP/4/) while holding down <kbd>⌘</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> if not on a Mac), for example.

For a complete reference, here is the used code:

```
var button = document.getElementById('source'),
    target = document.getElementById('target');

function handler(evt) {
    target.dispatchEvent(evt); // that's all the magic it takes
}

button.addEventListener(
    'click', // listen to a click event
    handler,
    false // no capture, i.e. do not catch events before children
);​
```

---

You may also find [this complete reference on DOM events](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents) useful  :)

Comment: I've already tried that but don't you get this error:
Uncaught Error: DISPATCH_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Events Exception 1?

Comment: @NimaIzadi I had tested only with Safari 5, in which it worked. Indeed, Chrome 21 throws a `DISPATCH_REQUEST_ERR`… and FF 14 throws `NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE`. Quite interesting. I'm trying to investigate some more.

Comment: `DISPATCH_REQUEST_ERR` comes from the fact that the event is [already dispatched](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20060413/events.html#Events-EventTarget-dispatchEvent). I tried to `stopPropagation()` but that doesn't change anything. Hence, I think only of two ways. First is to clone the event through `createEvent` and [`initMouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.initMouseEvent) (annoying to write, but can be in a helper function); this will probably not open links in the background as asked, due to the `isTrusted` attribute…

Comment: …(ref. for `isTrusted` [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events)). This should be tested in each browser though. Second way, to be tested too, and a bit ugly: add a timeout and `dispatch` the event later, after it has finished bubbling.

Comment: Great!
setTimeout works visibly on Webkit (Chrome 21 & Safari 6) but not on FF. It doesn't do anything on FF... (neither throw `NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE`)